# rownames in R 3.1.0 (for azure machine learning studio)

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a simple rownames(DF) into Azure machine learning studio, to transform the rownames of a dataframe into a variable, transforming that into a dataframe with a label and a code column, which needs to be the rownames of the original dataframe.

The rownames function was done in R 3.5.0 base package, so i don't have access to this, and I don't have access to Tibble ('cause it uses the rownames() function, in fact).

Answer (score 0):

You just need a base R solution to convert rownames to a column?

```
df$rownames <- rownames(df)
```